# 8-bit image displaying black on whole screen

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have an image and an array with filled up raster data... But the image shows just black please help....

```
IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(1,2,red,green,blue);
    BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED,icm);            
    byte[] a = ((DataBufferByte) buf.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

//Logically filled up the whole image data here

//showing the image

     JFrame jf = new JFrame("1-Bit BMP");
     jf.setSize(width,height);
     //jf.setResizable(false);
     JLabel jl = new JLabel();
     JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(jl);
     jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(buf));
     jf.add(js);
     jf.setVisible(true);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change your `IndexColorModel` like this....

```
IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(8,256,red,green,blue);
```

for 1-bit... 1,2
for 2-bit... 2,4
for 4-bit... 4,16
for 8-bit... 8,256

Also `IndexColorModel` is not required in 16 or more bits....

Comment: If you only have 1 bit image with 2 colors, you could also keep the `IndexColorModel`  as is, and instead change the `BufferedImage` type to `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` (works for 1, 2 and 4 bits).